# Run php code conditionally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I want to run the code on the basis or values returned from php array. If value is returned as disabled , offer with disabled status will not be matched.

This line of code is working fine .

```
if ($condition1 >= $offer1 AND $condition2 >= $offer2  AND 
$condition3 >= $offer3  AND  $condition4 >= $offer4     ) 
      {  //run code }
else {  //some error messages  }


$condition1 and all are numeric value 
$offer1  and all are numeric value
```

Sample output and array values

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
$offerstatus[] = $row['offer_status'];
//some more output
}
```

> Values stored in this array  $offerstatus[]  = enabled or disabled

these values are stored with reference to offer
**Sample Values**

```
offer   status 
offer1  enabled
offer2  enabled 
offer3  disable
offern  disable
```

or

```
condition     offer status
 50           51    enabled
100           99    enabled
122          865    disable
NNN          offern disable
```

I want to run the above query based on values returned from this array  **$offerstatus[]** .so that only those conditions are matched whose values are enabled.

**Question:** 
I want to run this code for all the values that are retunred as enabled , and want to match those conditions.

On the basis of sample Values

The above should automatically be turned like this

```
if ($condition1 >= $offer1 AND $condition2 >= $offer2     ) 
      {  //run code }
else {  //some error messages  }
```

Please let me know if the question is not well clarified.

Comment: How many offers can be maximum ?  And offer contain (1 and 0) or (enable and disable)?

Comment: Check at my answer and approve it if that help you

Comment: @Curious , There will be maximim 14 offers.

Comment: you have not clarified the question. first you say that $offer1  and all are numeric value. and then later you say that $offer1 contain enable and disable. you must also lets us that what does that condition variable contain the value.

Comment: $offer1 does not contain enable or disable , but $offerstatus is enable or disable. please see the edited question

Comment: ok i checked your edit. so you get offer and condition along with status means  `select offer,condition ,status from table` ?

Comment: NO, select  offerstatus from table ... condition1 and offer1 are count(), from two different tables stored in varilables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

condition and offer must be in array

```
$condition=array(50,100,122);
$offer=array(51,99,865);
```

Now filter the array those has value **enabled**

```
function filter_enabled($val){
    if($val=='enabled'){
        return true;
    }
}

$filtered_offerstatus=array_filter($offerstatus,'filter_enabled');
```

Now `$filtered_offerstatus` contains only those value which are **enabled** , now check if condition is greater than equal to offer

```
$check=false;
foreach($filtered_offerstatus as $key=>$value){

        if($condition[$key]>=$offer[$key]){
            $check=true;
        }
        else{
            $check=false;
            break; //if $condition is less than $offer it will get out of loop.
        }
}
```

Now if all value set to **true** the code will be executed otherwise **error message**

```
if($check===true){
    echo "Execute Code";
}
else{
    echo "Some Error Message";
}
```

> Note: we assume that $condition ,$offer and $offerstatus have the same length of array, otherwise this program will not work.

Comment: Can you please explain this part of code ...

foreach($filtered_offerstatus as $key=>$value){

        if($condition[$key]>=$offer[$key]){
          
I am not able to understnad  $key=>$value and  if($condition[$key]>=$offer[$key]){  ------ Where will they get these values

Comment: I must say, you have given a perfect solution . if it worked well

Comment: check this manual to understand foreach [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Note that $condition ,$offer and $offerstatus have same length of array. means if $condition have 14 value then $offer and $offerstatus must have 14 values. Otherwise this program will not work

Comment: this is true, all of them have equal lenth

Comment: Ok if you find my answer suitable and correct, then vote for it community and accept the answer.

Comment: for your last part ///if($check===true){
    echo "Execute Code";
How will I execute my code .. How will I know which conditions have been true and which code to run now . as this will change with status=enabled or disable
 $condition1 >= $offer1 AND $condition2 >= $offer2   and so on .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105294/discussion-between-curious-and-asif).

Comment: I am waiting for your in chat room

Answer (score 1):

You will want to not use the `>=` operators. Swap it out for `===`. Your $condition variables will also need to be string values enable/disable. Then your evaluation IF bloc would be similar to this:

```
if ('enabled' === 'enabled'  AND 'disabled' !== 'enabled') {
    //run code
} else {
    //some error messages 
}
```

Comment: i think $conditionn and $offern is another value, check at my answer

Comment: , The condition will be true only >= , it cant be == ., The code will only if  $condition1 >= $offer1 . and so on

Comment: what is the value in $condition1 ?

Comment: $condition1 and $offer1, contains COUNT() of some specific values, and  code will run if one count is higher than the others. $condition1 >= $offer1,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
/* SAMPLE VALUE */
$offerstatus = array('1'=>'enabled','2'=>'enabled','3'=>'disable');//in your case from your bdd

$condition1 = 15;
$offer1 =10;
$condition2 = 15;
$offer2 =10;


$one_condition_error=false;//boolean to check if all condition is true

foreach($offerstatus as $offer => $status){//foreach offerstatus
    if($status=='enabled'){//only if this offerstatus is enabled
        if(${'condition'.$offer} < ${'offer'.$offer}){// i check if conditionN < offerN : ${'test_'.$i}  -> $test1 if $i =1
            $one_condition_error=true;//one error detected
        }

    }       
}

if($one_condition_error){
    echo 'at least one offerstatus error';
}else{
    echo 'all offerstatus ok';

}
```

Comment: , can you please write some explanation to the code.

Comment: Sure i can, i have edited my answer with some explanation, as me in comment if you dont understand something