# Run PHP code with certain conditions enabled or disabled

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, for-loop

I have already asked this question here.
[Run php code conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776814/run-php-code-conditionally/35777174?noredirect=1#comment59253359_35777174)

I have made some modification to the db.
The answer given before might be correct , I have tried them but does not work.
Those answers might be above my PHP understanding.

**Below is rephrased version of the same question.**

The actual code that i want to replace

```
if ($condition1 >= $offer1 AND $condition2 >= $offer2  AND 
$condition3 >= $offer3  AND  $condition4 >= $offer4     ) 
      {  //run code }
else {  //some error messages  }

$condition1 and all are numeric value 
$offer1  and all are numeric value
```

I want to replace this code with the new one. sample below.

```
if ($offercurrent[0]>=$offerpoints[0] AND $offercurrent[1]>=$offerpoints[1]  AND 
$offercurrent[2]>=$offerpoints[2] AND  $offercurrent[3]>=$offerpoints[3]     ) 
      {  //run code }
else {  //some error messages  }

$offerstatus = enabled or disabled
$offercurrent = numeric values
$offerpoints = numeric values


$offercurrent   $offerpoints  status
 50               51           enabled
100               99           enabled
122               865          disable
NNN               offern       disable
```

Database values

```
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  
{
$offername[] = $row['name'];
$offercurrent[] = $row['current'];
$offerstatus[] = $row['status'];
$offerpoints[] = $row['points'];

}
```

**Question:**

The code should run only if offerstatus= enabled . one this  condition is met . it should check all the occurences of offercurrent and offerpoints.
I have tried  to replace the previous code with this one

```
    $check=false;
    for ($i=0;$i<count($offerstatus);$i++) { 
           //echo "$offerstatus[$i]";
            if ($offerstatus[$i]=="enabled")  { 
           if($offercurrent[$i]>=$offerpoints[$i]) {$check=true;}
            echo "$offername[$i]";}
                                          } 

    echo "$check";

if ($check=true) { //run code } 
else {//error messages}
```

With this code check alyways return 1 (true)
it only checks the first values and ignores the rest of the values.

Comment: you're assigning true to $check inside the if

Comment: if($offercurrent[$i]>=$offerpoints[$i]) . if this is true then check will be true.

Comment: `if ($check=true) ` needs to be `if ($check === true) ` or `if ($check == true) ` using a single `=` assigns a value to the variable rather than checking it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by adding else in the code .

```
$check=false;
for ($i=0;$i<=count($offerstatus);$i++) { 
       //echo "$offerstatus[$i]";
        if ($offerstatus[$i]=="enabled")  { 
       if($offercurrent[$i]>=$offerpoints[$i]) {$check=true;}
                       else{  $check=false;   
        break; //if $condition is less than $offer it will get out of loop.
                                   }
        }
                                      } 

if ($check=true) { //run code } 
else {//error messages}
```